# WPF DataGrid deselect row from above in DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a 3 tier datagrid where when you select an item below the parent, the parent item should be unselected. I use the SelectedItem property in all 3 DataGrids. Is there anyway I can deselect the parent row once the row beneath is selected?

I have my Selecteditem properties in a MVVM structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `SelectedItem` (or the property which is properly bind with the `SelectedItem`) of the Parent Grid(s) to `null`, that will work. You achieve this in several ways like, handling the `LostFocus` of the parent grids, handling the `SelectionChanged` or `GotFocus` of the child grids or creating a new dependency property for the `DataGrid` to achieve this new behaviour.

Comment: Thanks ,I worked out it out, I used the Getfocus in the view, I got the current item, got the Datacontext of the MVVM and did it that way, thanks!